# Google Photos won't stop syncing on iOS

Tags: ios, google

I have Google Photos installed on my iPhone 6S and would like it to stop automatically syncing my photos.  I like to view my pictures but don't want everything backed up.

I have gone into settings on the app and turned off "Backup & sync" but if I take a picture it still gets uploaded!  I've tried restarting the app and the iPhone but it still does it.

Comment: I would disable sync during cellular connection and just live with the options.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off [Background app refresh](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-turn-off-background-app-refresh-in-ios-7/)

Comment: That option does not seem to work.  The Google Photo iOS app continues to upload my photos even when I tell it not to.

Answer (score 0):

If you turned off back up & sync, then it should not upload the photos to the cloud. However, you can still view the photos in the app, but each picture that is not uploaded will have a no cloud sign -- a cloud icon with a line through it.

Comment: How do you know that the cloud icon works like that? Is it documented anywhere? The icon doesn't mean anything to me. Or the meaning of the crossed over cloud could be meaning "fine weather that day"

Comment: I think it makes sense that if there's a no cloud icon then the photos aren't backed up to the cloud. If you login to Google Photos on another device, you'd see that the photos with that icon on your phone won't be visible to you on the other device since they're not backed up.

Comment: This means that you have to use another device to check on your files... which doesn't make sense. I did try to use Google photos on the web from my iPhone, but no, it is impossible, they force you to use the app, at least as of the day I tried it 2022-03-26. Well, I get now how the whole thing is working, but to me, it's just a  bad UI.